# Binary Search Tree, adding the same element exception.

Tags: java, exception, binary-search-tree

I want to add an element to a BinarySearchTree. I have a condition that checks if the element is already in the tree and if it is I want to throw an exception. My problem is that I do not know what type, or what the name of this exception is. I was looking for DublicateItemException but it does not work. I am working with java. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java `TreeSet` simply returns `false` when you try to add an already-present element to the tree, but `Queue` sets an alternative precedent of throwing an `IllegalStateException`.  There's no exception built into Java for the case you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own exception for it.

Just create a new class `DuplicateItemException`, and make sure it extends `Exception`:

```
public static class DuplicateException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6188088059604835525L; //change the number, if needed - was auto generated by eclipse

}
```

If you want to use an existing class - maybe [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) might fit, though not perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own?

```
public class DuplicateItemException extends Exception
{
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to create a class for an exception